# Monotone class that is closed under unions

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ be a set, $E\subset X$ a set-algebra and $m$ the smallest monotone class containing $E$.
Let $Y=\{A\in m:A^\complement\in m\}$.

> I want to show that $Y$ is closed under countable unions

My idea was that for a sequence $(A_n)_{n}$ we can define $U_k=\bigcup_{i=1}^k A_i.$ Then $(U_k)_k$ is an increasing sequence. However, for that to hold, $Y$ should be closed under finite unions, which beforehand is not necessary.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: @Adayah Could you maybe help with the question as it is now?

Comment: I will try, but can't promise anything. I haven't solved it yet,

Comment: Since $E$ is an algebra, the monotone class $m$ is actually a $\sigma$-algebra, right? Using this, it shouldn't be difficult to prove the assertion.

Comment: @saz To show that $m$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is the final goal of this, so I cannot use that yet

Comment: From my point of view it would be much more natural to prove that $Y$ is a monotone class (i.e. closed under countable monotone unions...)

Comment: @saz But how would you show that $Y$ is closed under countable unions?

Comment: I also think at this point it is more natural to show that $Y$ is a monotone class, i.e. closed under countable monotone unions, not all countable unions. This leads to showing that $m$ is closed under complements.

Comment: Should E subset  X be E subset P(X)?

Comment: What is a monotone class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Lemma 1** For all $A \in m, B \in E$ we have $A \cap B \in m$.

**Proof**. Let

$$\mathcal{A} = \{ A \in m : (\forall B \in E) \, A \cap B \in m \}.$$

Since $E$ is an algebra of sets, $E \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Moreover $\mathcal{A}$ is a monotone class: for instance let $A_1 \subseteq A_2 \subseteq A_3 \subseteq \ldots$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{A}$ and let $B \in E$. From the assumption each $A_n \cap B$ is in $m$ and $A_1 \cap B \subseteq A_2 \cap B \subseteq A_3 \cap B \subseteq \ldots$ is an ascending sequence, so the set

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cap B = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cap B)$$

is in $m$, hence $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \in m$. It's similar to prove that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under descending sequences, using

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n \cap B = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (A_n \cap B).$$

Hence $\mathcal{A}$ is a monotone class containing $E$, therefore $m \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ which implies our claim. $\ \square$

**Lemma 2** For all $A, B \in m$ we have $A \cap B \in m$.

**Proof**. Fix $A \in m$ and let

$$\mathcal{B} = \{ B \in m : A \cap B \in m \}.$$

From lemma 1 it follows that $E \subseteq \mathcal{B}$. Moreover $\mathcal{B}$ is a monotone class: for instance let $B_1 \subseteq B_2 \subseteq B_3 \subseteq \ldots$ be a sequence of sets in $\mathcal{B}$. From the assumption $A \cap B_1 \subseteq A \cap B_2 \subseteq A \cap B_3 \subseteq \ldots$ is an ascending sequence of sets in $m$, so the set

$$A \cap \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (A \cap B_n)$$

is in $m$, hence $\displaystyle \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \in \mathcal{B}$. It's similar to prove that $\mathcal{B}$ is closed under descending sequences, using

$$A \cap \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (A \cap B_n).$$

Hence $\mathcal{B}$ is a monotone class containing $E$, therefore $m \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ which implies our claim. $\ \square$

Now that we know that $m$ is closed under finite intersections, it follows immediately that $Y$ is closed under finite unions, which is what you were missing.